# Save data through Hidden field in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table **Group** and a table **Ledger**

`Ledger/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@ledger) do |f| %>
  <% if @ledger.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ledger.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ledger from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ledger.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label :under_group %><br>
    <%= f.select(:under_group, options_for_select(Group.all.map { |group| [group.name, group.id, {'data-group_type'=>group.group_type}] })) %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is Form of Ledger where under_groups gives list of all the group entries
Both Group and Ledgers have a field "Group_type"

So i want is when user choose a group in Form, it should take data from Group_type of Groups and save it to Group_type of Ledgers

I tried hidden fields but they dont run real time
Other is saving from Controller which i dont want to do
Is there any other way? Ajax/jQuery maybe?

This gives

```
<select name="ledger[under_group]" id="ledger_under_group"><option data-group_type="0" value="1">Primary(Assets)</option>
<option data-group_type="0" value="1">Primary(Liabilities)</option>
<option data-group_type="0" value="2">Primary(Income)</option>
```

I want value to be saved in under_group column and save group_type in group_type column of that same table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<%= f.select :group_type, options_for_select(under_groups) %>
```

Comment: Hello that didnt help, What i want is when User select Group in ledger form, and submit it, Group_type(From ledger) should automatically be saved(from Group's Group_type)